# Using recursion to find which number is bigger

Tags: python

Hello all I am trying to find out which of two numbers is bigger using recursion and without using the > or the < symbols. Is this even possible? I am only allowed to use + or -
thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? This isn't a "do my hw for me" site.

Comment: "Is this even possible" Yes, of course it is.

Comment: I am not sure where to begin with this question

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: I am learn python by myself these are some questions I got from student who have taken computers courses before

Comment: The user's name made my hole day happy, I didn't notice, but by sure is very great and fun :), considere a change of user name, just an advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show you a test implementation in Haskell that would solve the question. It's not the best solution, but your instructor doesn't appear to be looking for efficiency, just some deep thinking about the problem.

```hs
-- |'myMax' takes two strictly positive ints and returns
-- the larger of the two.
myMax :: Int -> Int -> Int
myMax 0 y = y
myMax x 0 = x
myMax x y = myMax (x-1) (y-1)
```

Comment: Is that haskell code?

Comment: @DamianLattenero yes, thus my text above the code ;)

Comment: in line 2 is it saying that the function MyMax and if the first number is 0 it means the second number is the larger?

Comment: @AdamSmith sure! Hahaha I thanked  in haskell code first, then translate it, well I by sure would up vote, but the Tag is python... It would be not correct even if I want to, want you add the python idea also?

Comment: @DamianLattenero no, I specifically did not answer in Python because this is an elementary question intended to create a bit of thought in the pupil about how recursion works and what makes a number "bigger" than another. Feeding code to the student does him harm in this case.

Comment: @helpmeplz exactly so.

Comment: @AdamSmith good point

Comment: If that's the case I will up vote for good explain in recursion matters

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is possible, using recursion you have to consider that positive integer (with 0) could be represented as 0 or the next of a positive number. Considering that, if the number is not 0, you can go a step back, and ask if it is 0, and continue, with code it would be:

```
def greater_than(a,b):
  if(a == 0):
    return b!=0
  elsif(b == 0):
    return True
  else:
    return greater_than(a-1,b-1)
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help

Comment: @helpmeplz no problem, if you understood what I've done, the job is done, if you want more explain to the answer I can answer more doubts and question you have, let me know

Comment: Ah, one last thing, don't forget next time add some code you tried before you ask a question! So the users will not down vote the question. And don't forget to mark one answer as accepted, the one who helped you with the problem most